# Nodejs block code execution until it receives TCP command (pending a GUI event)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, node-modules, event-loop

I'm writing a TCP server from Java + Rhino to nodeJS ...

And I have a problem with blocking execution of code while no blocking TCP listener (`socket.on(‘data’, ()=>{}`)…

Why I need that : I need that to have sync respond from pending a GUI...  in Java it was covered by child TCP listener process and in the main process there was a loop like :

```
// simulate message loop
        boolean enddialog = false;
        int endtype = 0;
        try {
            while (!end) {
                String s = "";
                s = ess.dequeueCommand();
                if (s.equals("mennu1")) {
                    end = true;
                    endtype = 0;
                }
                if (s.equals("menu2")) {
                    end = true;
                    endtype = 1;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Deasync helpt me much with making DB calls ‘sync’…

```
    var deasync = require('deasync');

module.exports = function DB(){
  var knex = require('knex')(require("./../../config").DB);

  this.executeRowsetParam = (sql, param) => {
    let done = false;
    knex.raw(sql, param).then((r => {
      done = r;
    })).catch((e => {
      throw "Error in query "+ e
    }))
    deasync.loopWhile(function () { return !done; });
    return done
  }
}
```

I have tried deasync but it will block event listener …
I made it work with Promise but it won't work in this case because of a code base that is written in js for "old" server and there is no way for me to rewrite that code base
Promise example :

```
return new Promise( (res) => {
            if(this.sel == null){
                let callb = (d)=>{
                    var ed = Buffer.from(d);
                    this.GetDataStricte(ed).then((da)=>{
                        res(da);
                        this.socket.removeListener('data',callb);
                    });
                }
                this.sel = this.socket.on('data',callb);
            }
           
        });
```

Could you help me?

Comment: You can't "block code execution" and wait for some other event in node.js.  The node.js world does not work that way.  Blocking code execution would be blocking the event loop which would mean you could never get the event you're waiting for.  If you're porting to node.js, you have to rewrite for the asynchronous execution model.  There is no way around it for network I/O.

Comment: How about add-ons ? Can I write add-on that coud run as sub process or start some sub process of node with tcp server that would still work while I stop execution ?

Comment: If you're trying to do blocking network I/O, then node.js is just the wrong platform for you.  If you back up and describe the overall problem you're trying to solve (not the solution you're trying to make work), then we can probably help show you how to solve it with non-blocking I/O.  So far, what you've done here is like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you've described issues with your attempted solution to some problem, but you're down the wrong architectural path so we can only help when you describe the original problem.

Comment: You can do anything you want from a native code add-on because it's just native code that can do anything native code can do.  I rather doubt that is required to solve your overall problem though, but until we understand what the real problem is, we can't advise on how to use the node.js architecture to solve it.